# How to create a file with multiple lines and / - Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, echo

How can I create a file with multiple lines, / and " ?

I am trying to create a scss file where I the text has multiple lines, / and "
Is there any way where I don't have

Here is the code I have been working:

```
echo '
//== IMPORTS
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@import "global/variables/_v-base.scss";
@import "global/variables/_v-sitenamegoeshere2018.scss";
@import "_base.scss";


//== THEME SPECIFIC STYLES ' > site.scss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line in output file == one `echo`.

Each `echo` must have its own redirection to file (first - output `>`, non-first - append `>>`).

Special symbols must be quoted by `^` sign preceeded the symbol.

To output empty line use `echo.`.

```
@echo off
echo //== IMPORTS > site.scss
echo //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- >> site.scss
echo. >> site.scss
echo @import "global/variables/_v-base.scss"; >> site.scss
echo @import "global/variables/_v-sitenamegoeshere2018.scss";>> site.scss
echo @import "_base.scss"; >> site.scss
echo. >> site.scss
echo. >> site.scss
echo //== THEME SPECIFIC STYLES >> site.scss
```

Comment: This is simply not true: `Each echo must have its own redirection to file` If you enclose a (code block) of echo commands in parentheses you can have a single redirection of the block `(echo foo&echo bar) >site.scss` much easier to read.